# Clickable KPI tabs that update the filters

Tags: tabs, dashboard, analytics, google-analytics

In a system, I am working on I want to create a KPI which is also a tab, like in the image from google analytics and I want it to affect the filters as well:

1. Do you know any reference that behaves like that?
2. Any important point I should take into consideration?

[image]

Comment: in terms of filters, are you thinking there's a filter bar above the entire dataset?

Comment: Yes, a set of filters that will be activated when the user clicks on one of the KPI and can also be activated manually